# Interval instance has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-structures

I am running this on my local and it is running fine but when I submit this code online I get this error -> " Interval instance has no attribute '**getitem**' ". Can someone help me with this? I am using python 2.7 here. argument -> intervals refer to the list of tuples. Example -> [(1,3),(2,6),(8,10),(15,18)]

```
def merge(intervals):
        intervals.sort()
        stack = []
        start = 0
        end =1
        for interval in intervals:
            if not stack:
                stack.append(interval)
            else:
                b = stack[-1]
                if b[end] >= interval[start]:
                    stack[-1] = (b[start], max(interval[end],b[end]))
                else:
                    stack.append(interval)
        return stack
```

Comment: Paste the whole stacktrace.

Comment: (nevermind ... )

Comment: If this is for some online judge, I'd guess that `intervals` isn't actually a list of tuples you're being given. Try printing it out to see what it actually is?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 186, in 
    result = obj.merge(v)
  File "/tmp/judge/solution.py", line 14, in merge
    if b[end] >= interval[start]:
AttributeError: Interval instance has no attribute '__getitem__' 
@AmitTripathi

Comment: The test case they passing is a list of tuples @tzaman

Comment: @ShaishavGarg link to question?

Comment: @ShaishavGarg if it actually were, you would not get that error. If this is for [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-intervals/description/), they have a custom interval object, for which the definition is provided in the question.

Comment: Given a collection of intervals, merge all overlapping intervals.

For example:

Given [1,3],[2,6],[8,10],[15,18],

return [1,6],[8,10],[15,18].

Make sure the returned intervals are sorted.
@AmitTripathi

Comment: I am submitting this code on (www.interviewbit.com) @tzaman

Comment: `[1,3],[2,6],[8,10],[15,18]` its not list of tuples. Its multiple lists. Online judge is calling your `merge` method or you are calling from your code? Is it an interview question?

Comment: I know this is not a list of tuples. It is just a for reference to the problem. The list being passed is a list of tuples. However my code is also not limited whether I am passing list of tuples or list of lists. It would be the same anyway. Yes this is a interview question @AmitTripathi

Comment: Voting to close because this is now about debugging the online judge rather than your code. The code as posted works fine for a list of tuples.

Comment: @ShaishavGarg the code works. The most probable reason I can give without looking at the question and its contraints is `interval` is an object which doesn't support inexing. This question should be closed.